# Could you add the Stack Exchange site name on all questions feeds?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com

Could you add the Stack Exchange site on the question's title of Stack Exchange [all questions feed](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions)?

Something like:

**stackoverflow.com - convert string to date(dd/MM/yyyyy) format in c#**

**gamedev.stackexchange.com - Architecture a for a central renderer rather than self-rendering**

**servefault.com - Allow someone to join a local LAN via a public ip?**

Adding this information will improve the usability helping the reader to better skim through the feeds.

Comment: I'm all for this, except I think the site name should be at the end: _Convert string to date(dd/MM/yyyy) format in C# - stackoverflow.com_

Comment: @Maxim uhm..i thought the same at [first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/56d53e9c-2b36-4d9e-8688-4e7ee7ea029e/view-source) , then i switched to "site name at the beginning" solution because i think it allows you to skip the site you don't like without even reading the question's title.

Comment: you can eliminate sites you don't want from the list if you're logged in (RSS too).  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/customizing-stackexchange-com/

Comment: @David i'm aware of it and i'm currently using that cool feature, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. We decided to go with the site name at the end, as Maxim suggested.